# OnPress State update via AsyncStorage the screen is not re-rendering

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I've `setItem` in `Home.js` file as:

```
    AsyncStorage.setItem('myValue', JSON.stringify(3))
```

Now in another file called `Ask.js` I've a button where I'm calling it:

```
    const [val, setVal] = useState("1");
...
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                AsyncStorage.getItem("myValue").then((value) => {
                    setVal(value)
                    console.log(value + ' and ' + val)
                });
            }}>
```

Based on the `console.log` When this button is pressed it logs `1 and 3` which seems like the value is not updated but if I press it again it'll print `3 and 3` which means the `useState` value was updated but it didn't rerender.

So how do I re-render?

Comment: -> setValue(value), you are not using the setter.

Comment: What is val(value)? I think it should be setVal(value).

Comment: @Konstantin It was a type... just fixed it... It still doesn't work

Comment: @ZenoDallaValle yup that was a typo. But. even fixing it still it doesn't re-render

Comment: i believe u can try to use `await AsyncStorage.setItem`. You should inspect your local storage and see if your value is updated.

Comment: also using a getter (console.log('val')) right after a setter (setVal) will not reflect the correct value because the value is not set immediately( setstate is an async  method). You have to render the value in your return block, don't test it with console.log

Answer (score 0):

The problem is :
you are not using setVal to update the value.
It should be like this.

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                AsyncStorage.getItem("myValue").then((value) => {
                    setVal(value)
                    console.log(value + ' and ' + val)
                });
            }}>
```

Comment: the `val(value)` was a typo. I edited it but it still doesn't work. Like it updates the value but it is not re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your example. I created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-water-suj5h?file=/src/Ask.js) in react-native. For me is working fine.

**EDIT 1:**

> When this button is pressed it logs 1 and 3 which seems like the value
> is not updated

That's because of the asynchronous nature of state hook (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)). It is normal.
You didn't post the code in which you expect to see the change of val, I guess the problem is there.